# ffmpeg combine multiple FHD videos with concat option, but output is HD

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine multiple 1920x1080 videos(.MTS) with concat option, but output resolution is 1280x720.

How can I combine multiple videos with keeping resolution?

Script is below.

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i content_dir.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a output.MTS`

and the content of input text is below

```
file '1.MTS'
file '2.MTS'
file '3.MTS'
file '4.MTS'
```

the information of source videos is below.

```
video codec h264_nvenc
audio codec ac3
```

the output of command prompt is below.

```
Input #0, concat, from 'E:\VideoMaker3\tmp_videos_o3_1\content_dir.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

Thank you.

**Add**

This problem was caused by a little mistake. One of the input videos was 1280x720, so the resolution of the output was not FHD.
Thank you guys who gave me a comment.

Comment: Are these BD or DVD rips?

Comment: Have you checked resolution of input files?

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i 1.MTS -i 2.MTS -i 3.MTS -i 4.MTS`

Comment: @Gyan
No.
I generated a video from an audio with ffmpeg, opening video and ending video with adobe premiere pro. Then I tried to combine these three into one video, but I got huge number of error messages like this.
`[mp4 @ 000001edf3e200c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 177554284, current: 59186559; changing to 177554285. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`
Therefore, I have no choice to combine multiple MTS videos.

Comment: @mouviciel
Yes.
All input videos are generated by the script like this.
`ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 32768 -i audio.mp3 -f lavfi -i color=size=1920x1080:rate=30:color=white -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=size=1920x1080:mode=cline:rate=30:colors=0x696969@0.8[v];[1:v][v]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,format=yuva420p,drawtext=fontfile=font_path:text=text2:fontsize=65:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=0x696969@0.8:borderw=3:x=70:y=810[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -cq 19 -c:a ac3 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 29.97 output.MTS`

Comment: @llogan
Thank you so much.
One of the video is 1280x720, so the result was not FHD.
It makes sence.

Comment: @Zawazawa You can add your solution as an answer using the "Post Your Answer" button below. It will help you gain reputation so you can gain access to more features on this site.